# How to get a live cd to auto install software into ubuntu

Tags: iso

I should note, I used Active iso in windows 7 to burn the disc (Samurai-WTF) I am required to load into ubuntu to run penetration testing..ANYWAY, I am using a virtual machine..latest version of ubuntu 10.11 and cannot get the software to run.. is it the iso burner? I wouldn't think so, but ubuntu is only reading it as a data disc.. I even downloaded a second iso and burned again to ensure not a bad iso..short of running the hashes, Im sure this is good software. do I need to do command line via terminal?

Sorry, sleepy, frustrated student...

Thanks in advance..

Comment: If you look at the CD you burnt under Windows, what files exist at the top level?  Also, is it possible that the CD burning application didn't completely burn the CD?  (e.g. if the CD-R couldn't fit everything).

Answer (score 3):

Samurai-WTF is a live CD, you don't need to open it in Ubuntu or install anything, you need to set up your VirtualBox instance to boot from that CD. Or just boot your computer from that CD.

Comment: Hence my frustration...ALWAYS the simple things...it didnt help I had to reinstall ubuntu in vmware8 twice to get it to see the drive to begin with...many thanks..

Comment: nooby student, I can help you. Let me set u[ a chat room, stay on the line please :)